# Bootstrap - Toggle sidebar with icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such a layout:

[image]

I would like that when one clicks the orange button, the sidebar shrinks and leaves only the icons visible. And for the mobile should totally shrink and when one clicks the button only the icons should be visible. The behaviour should be like [this](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.5/widgets.html#) but I don't understand how to make it work.

For now I have my header:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#menu-toggle" onclick="toggle()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">...</a>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to make it collapse when one clicks.. Thanks

Comment: Could you  please post all of the code in your navbar.

Comment: Be sure to call the exact name of the class of the button that triggers the toggle function in jquery or javascript. Also check your jquery links if it uses the exact links. Else it won't work.

Comment: Have look to this plugin: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/#navmenu-offcanvas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a rough way you could assign 2 classes (one for the icon, one for the relative text) for example, class "icon" and class "text", and on button click, toggle (hide and show) the element with the class "text". Then in a callback you could animate the resizing of the sidebar.

Edit2: Improved example

```js
$('#togglebutton').click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500) { //your chosen mobile res
      $('.text').toggle(300);
    } else {
      $('.menu').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
      }, 350);
    }
});
```

```css
​.wrapper { width: 100% }
.menu {
      background: #222;
      float: left;
      display: block;
}

.icon { max-width: 1em }

.menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

.menu li { margin: 0 }

.menu a, .menu a:visited {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.text {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
}

.content { display: block; }

button { margin: 1em; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .text {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="icon" src="http://bit.do/iconUrl">
          <p class="text">Text 1</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="icon" src="http://bit.do/iconUrl">
          <p class="text">Text 2</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <button id="togglebutton">&#9776;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it was useful to have a general idea of my suggestion.

Comment: That's clearer now... but how to reproduce the behaviour OP has described in the its link post?

Comment: You mean the "__...for the mobile should totally shrink...__", with css media queries, the .text class should be hidden under a certain resolution width

Comment: I mean : from your code snippet, how to create an example like this one: http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.5/widgets.html#

Comment: My code snippet is a general example. I'm a newbie on stackoverflow so I could have misunderstood, in this site who gives an answer must implement a work on request? Sorry, if I've produced an answer that doesn't fit the site purposes I can delete it.

Comment: Don't delete it... improve it instead.

Answer (score 6):

***Update 2019***

**Bootstrap 4**

This is also possible in Bootstrap 4, but still requires extra CSS to handle the sidebar state.

https://www.codeply.com/p/e5IcpodgE2

**Bootstrap 3**

You can create an "off canvas" sidebar, and then use Bootstrap's responsive utility classes to toggle display of the icons.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="column col-sm-3 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav" id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> <span class="collapse in hidden-xs">Link 1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> <span class="collapse in hidden-xs">Stories</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> <span class="collapse in hidden-xs">Saved</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> <span class="collapse in hidden-xs">Refresh</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- main right col -->
            <div class="column col-sm-9 col-xs-11" id="main">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="offcanvas" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></a>
                <p>
                    content...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/uunNOeQAqo